# How to get data from ajax.done()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../../getposts.php"
}).done(function(posts) { 
    var postsjson = $.parseJSON(posts);
});
```

How do I use the variable `postsjson` outside the `.done()` function, or how do I declare it global?

I can't pass it to another function, because I want to use the array later on, and not when the ajax is completed.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You can just declare a global variable outside your function, and set that variable equal to `posts` once it's ready. However, there's no way to know for sure when that global variable will have anything in it.

Comment: In JS, any global variable is technically a property of the `window` object. So you should be able to set `window.myVar = posts;` and voila -- instant global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just define the variable outside of the ajax call:

```
var postsjson;

$.ajax({
    url: "../../getposts.php"
}).done(function(posts) { 
    postsjson = $.parseJSON(posts);
});
```

Then you can use it outside. Likewise, if you just leave of the `var`, it will declare it globally, but that is not recommended.

As pointed out by SLaks, you won't be able to immediately use the data you get from the AJAX call, you have you wait for the `done` function to be run before it will be initialized to anything useful.

Comment: That won't help; AJAX is asynchronous.  The variable will not be initialized until some time later.

Comment: The question isn't asking when they can access the data, or what it will hold, it's asking how they can access the data outside of the anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you! It was actually that simple :)

Answer (score 4):

The cool thing is that the promise returned from the Ajax function can be used in many different ways, here are some:

```
var XHR = $.ajax({
    url: "../../getposts.php"
});


function somethingElse() {
    XHR.done(function(posts) { 
       var postsjson = $.parseJSON(posts);
    });
}
```

--

```
function myAjax(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function doSomething(url) {
    var postsjson = myAjax(url).done(parsePosts);
}

function parsePosts() {
     return $.parseJSON(posts);
}

doSomething("../../getposts.php");
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable before calling ajax.

Simple Sample:

```
var postsjson;

$.ajax({
    url: "../../getposts.php"
}).done(function(posts) { 
    postsjson = $.parseJSON(posts);
});

console.info(postsjson); // Use here for example
```